# Change the «voice» played with a button in iOS app

Tags: ios, audio, settings, avfoundation

I have a soundboard app that says some phrases, but now I want to be able to change from male/female voice, the thing is I have no idea how to make this. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using `AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer` to play the sounds.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can be a bit hard to do !

You need change the Pitch of the voices, if you raise will have a higher pitch (can be defined as female), if you decrease the pitch its give to you a low sound (can be defined as male)!

The simplest way is definitely playing the áudio in a different sample rate, but it change the speed of  your audio :-(

The hard and right way to do it is build a Pitch Shift algorithm, its can be done in time domain (PSOLA, SOLA, WSOLA) or in Frequency domain (Phase Vocoder) !

Some of these techniques can disfigure the original voice (can change the phase and the envelope) looking very artificial, you can do a especific question about this methods in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ for a more detailed answer !